# User Profile Privacy screen with comma separated String

Tags: arrays, string, privacy, private-members, user-profile

I have a listView with many fields and CheckBox next to each field. Screen similar to a FaceBook Profile screen with Privacy setting to each field. So friends can not see those fields if marked as Private.

On selection of CheckBox, i have to create a comma separated String.

Example, 
FirstName Text --->  isFirstNamePrivate boolean

LastName  Text ---> isLastNamePrivate boolean
...

I have to create a

```
            String str = "FirstName,LastName"
```

if both are marked as Private.

If only isFirstNamePrivate is true then
                String str = "FirstName"

Also if i receive a comma separated String from Service, with that i have to make those Boolean array.

Given::

```
            String[] fieldNamesArray = "field1","field2","field3","field4","field5"};
            Boolean[] isfieldPrivate = {true,false,true,false,true};
            // fieldNamesArray.length will be equal to isfieldPrivate.length
```

Need to create below commaSeparatedStr from above given arrays.

```
            //
            String commaSeparatedStr = "field1,field3,field5";
```

Question is:

1) What is the optimized way to create a comma separated String.
2) What is the optimized way to create the Boolean array from the commaSeparatedString  avoiding  for loop on  commaSeparatedStr .contains(str[n])

Given::

```
        String[] fieldNamesArray = "field1","field2","field3","field4","field5"};
        String commaSeparatedStr = "field1,field3,field5";
```

Need to create below Boolean array with commaSeparatedStr from above 2 arrays.

```
            Boolean[] isfieldPrivate = {true,false,true,false,true};
         // fieldNamesArray.length will be equal to isfieldPrivate.length     
        //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the question part here?
If you are asking for a suggestion:
If there are 5 fields and first 3 are selected, make your string like
{1,1,1,0,0}
and pass it to your webservice. This would lighten the data package size.

Comment: Service accepts only comma separated strings ( fieldnames) . Question is, need a optimized way to create just comma separated string based on the list of check boxes selected.   Also, service will provide back such a comma separated string to be used in edit screen. Where user can change privacy settings again.

Comment: so did i answer your query?